# SurfaceView is distorted after switching back to App

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview

If i switch back from the home menu to my App sometimes the SurfaceView gets distorted like this:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot2014q2y4pkbtj7.png

The xml layout of the surfaceview looks like this:

```
> <com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath.DrawingView
>     android:id="@+id/surface"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Any solutions how i can fix this distortion?

Merry christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the surfaceview is destoryed when you leave the app, you can redraw the stuff to the surfaceview when it restart.

Comment: the surfaceCreated() Event starts if i go back from homescreen to my app and in the surfaceCreated() i restart my drawingThread so the surface gets redrawn

Comment: It happens also if i turn off my screen with the power button and then turn it back on again. Then i also get this distortion. Is there an event if the user turns the screen off?

Comment: post more code about the surfaceview and draw thread, please.

Comment: mRunningThread.interrupt(); will not stop the render thread immediately, maybe the surfaceview is locked by the old thread, and the new render thread can not redraw the surfaceview.

Comment: but i do: mRunningThread.Stop(); after interrupt which sets mIsRunning to false

Comment: sorry, i can not find the solution for this.